# Does sorting Angular reactive form array really requires sorting both controls and value?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've implemented formArray sortBy function in my angular app by sorting the formArray value and patch it after the sorting.

```
sortBy(FieldName: string) {
  let array = this.myItems.value;
  array.value.sort((a, b) => a[FieldName] - b[FieldName]);
  array.controls.sort((a, b) => a.value[FieldName] - b.value[FieldName]);
  this.myForm.controls.myItems.patchValue(array);
}
```

[Working Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ethos9?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

As you can see I had to sort both the formArray controls and its value.

My question is, Should I really sort it both or there is a better practice or a build in way of doing it. It looks like the controls and the value should be binded somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to "kinda" sort by both, though you can make a one-liner of it. We need to remember, when you call `myItems.value`, this is just a regular JS object, and the formarray is no longer tied to this, in the sense that if you modify `myItems.value` afterwards, it will not reflect in the formarray, as the formarray is an array of formcontrols/formgroups, not a regular JS array. The `myItems.value` will also just reflect the current state of the formarray value, so if you assign it to a variable and then change the value of the formarray, the assigned variable will have the original value.

So as for the oneliner... You can do

```
this.myItems.setValue(this.myItems.value.sort((a, b) => a[FieldName] - b[FieldName]));
```

And as mentioned in other answer, remove the bracket when building the form:

```
myItems: myFormArray
```

YOUR MODIFIED **[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ipyi4s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Thanks for saying 'regular JS object'. I had to here it.

Answer (score 3):

Just sorting by `control` is enough.

First, set `myItem` to `this.form` without bracket.

```
this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
  header: ['hello form'],
  myItems: myFormArray,
});
```

Then sort your `FormArray` by `controls`.

```
sortBy(FieldName: string) {
  this.myItems.controls.sort((a, b) => a.value[FieldName] - b.value[FieldName]);
}
```

If you need sorted `myArray`, you can get it by `this.myForm.getRawValue().myItems`.

Comment: Thanks, bracket removed. Still my main doubt here was about the values that stored both in the array value and in the controls value. I'm afraid that ignoring it might cause bugs in the future